# How to register a MS Word Blog account programatically

Tags: wordpress, ms-word, vsto

The only way to get a Word document onto WordPress without distorting the format seem to be through the blog post template.  And believe me, I have tried many other ways, using htmltidy, htmlawed and other code to clean the Word generated HTML page.
[image]

To do so, you need to register a new WordPress account.
[image]

Unfortunately for me, my users lack the mental capacity to fill in this for themselves. Assume that I already have the blog url, username, and password, how can I programmatically register an blog account for the user via VBA or C# VSTO AddIn?